# Regex to exclude [ unless preceded by \

Tags: java, regex

How do I write a regex that accepts an expression that contains any number of any characters except for '`[`', unless '`[`' is preceded by '`\`' ?

Example:

```
this is text \\[ this also [$ this isn't any more
```

From the above text, "`this is text \\[ this also`" should be accepted, and the rest shouldn't. I wrote something like:

```
[.[^\\\\[]]*
```

to exclude the '`[`' but have no idea how to allow it to contain '`\\[`' and the rest of the text also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will match all characters that are either not equal to `[` or equal to a `[` preceded by `\`:

```
([^\[]|(?<=\\)\[)+
```

If you want a simple pass/fail for an entire string, just add the start/end-line characters to the regex:

```
^([^\[]|(?<=\\)\[)+$
```

Comment: This did allright, except you were missing an '\' before the '[' in the "[^[]". Thanks.

Comment: Fixed my answer.  The `\\` is not necessary in all regex implementations, since in the given context it is a character class, but I am not familiar with Java regex.

Comment: Yes, this appears to work. Here is the escaped version for use in a Java string: `[^\\[]|(?<=\\\\)\\[)+`.

Answer (score 4):

```
([^\[]|\\\[)*
```

This accepts a sequence of ((anything except `[`) or (`\[`)).

In general, if you want to accept a string where certain characters need escaping, e.g. `abcd`, the regex that matches it is:

```
([^abcd]|\\[abcd])*
```

**Edit:**

This regex can be used with `Matcher.find` to iterate over all the sections that are within/outside `[]`:

```
\[(?:[^\[]|\\\[)*\]|(?:\\\[|[^\[])+
```

(Double all the backslashes when putting it in a Java string; I'm leaving them out for legibility.)

This will split the string `abc[ def \[ asd \] ]\[ dasd[ \] ]` into `abc`, `[ def \[ asd \] ]`, `\[ dasd`, and `[ \] ]`.

Comment: If I then write input "first \\[ second [ third" this gives me the output 
"first \"," second "," third"
but I would like: 
"first \\[ second ", " third".
So, I want \\[ to be contained in the expression, and [ to mark end of the expression.

Comment: It looks like your end goal is to split a string, but I don't see exactly what your criteria is. (Splitting on `\\[`?) Can you update your answer to contain more details on what you're trying to accomplish? This might be a case of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Sorry. Yes, my end goal would be to split a string. More detailed: I need to split it in 2 types of segments: segments starting by '[' and ending in ']', and segments outside these. However, the second type can contain '[' if it is preceded by '\'. So, that means a second type of segment could be "first \\[ second" but not "first [ second". So, I asked just for a part of the problem: keeping a segment if it contains '\\[', but discarding it if it starts by only '['. Hm, I don't see how it qualifies for XY.

Comment: Did you test your solution? I'm struggling to get it to work. Perhaps you can escape your pattern as it would be used in a Java string?