# Excluding regex matches that are preceded by a certain character

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I have the following:

```
Regex urlRx = new Regex(@"((https?|ftp|file)\://|www.)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+(/[A-Za-z0-9\?\#\&\=;\+!'\(\)\*\-\._~%]*)*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This matches all URLs, but I'd like to exclude those that are preceded by the characters `"` or `'`.  I've been trying to achieve this using other solutions ([Regex to exclude [ unless preceded by \](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573652/regex-to-exclude-unless-preceded-by)) but haven't been able to get it to pass.

If I have this, I should get a match:

```
The brown fox www.google.com
```

However, if I have this:

```
The brown fox <a href="www.google.com">boo</a>
```

I should not get a match, because of the `"`.  How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a **negative lookbehind**: Prefix your regular expression by `(?<!["'])`.

Explanation:

- `(?<!...)` means: The stuff directly *preceding* the current position must not match `...`.
- `["']` is simply a character group containing the two characters you want to exclude.

Note: Inside `@"..."` strings, double qoutes are escaped by doubling them, so your code will read:

```
Regex urlRx = new Regex(@"(?<![""'])((https?|ftp|file)...
```

In VB:

```
Dim urlRx As New Regex("(?<![""'])((https?|ftp|file)...
```